# Rewiring a boiler’s c wire for a smart thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I want to swap out my low-voltage Honeywell for a Nest E thermostat. When I took the Honeywell off the wall I confirmed that I’ve got a C wire running up to the thermostat but when I wired up the Nest it wouldn’t turn on. Below is a picture of the wiring at the boiler. I had a plumber look at it while he was visiting about another issue, and he said I’ve got all the necessary wiring but he didn’t know how it’d need to be rewired.

I bought a C wire adapter in case I need it for this project, but need a little help figuring out the wiring.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the furnace turned on?  Check the power at the transformer (red and white wires).

Comment: Can you post pictures of the wiring diagram for your boiler, or a make and model at least?

Comment: It's a Lennox GSB8-112E

Comment: well that second photo makes a difference,  where does that gray cable (that has the paper tag that says "thermostat" go to? a phot of the diagram to the on the left silde of the top phot may help too.

Comment: @Jasen -- that cable goes to the LWCO, best I can tell

Comment: C is one of the two two screw terminals on the tranformer, whichever one is 24V (ish) different to red on the brown wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As it turns out, C is staring you in the face

As it turns out, the transformer is sitting right in the middle of your photos, and by matching the wiring diagrams from [your boiler's installation manual](https://resources.lennox.com/fileuploads/d073f89f-a6c3-4735-912f-3fb2c05cf413Lennox_GSB8-E_IOM.pdf) to the wiring in your photo, we can determine that the C terminal on your transformer is the one with the white, black, and striped wires connected to it.  So, you can attach the spare blue wire from your brown thermostat cable to the C terminal on your transformer and use that as your C wire.

Comment: I added the blue wire to that terminal and now the Nest reads no C wire.

Comment: @adsigel -- that's odd.  Do you get about 24-27VAC between R and C at the nest, and between the two terminals of the boiler transformer?

Comment: This ended up being the correct wiring. The reason the Nest wasn’t working was an unrelated power issue with the furnace (now resolved).

Comment: @adsigel -- what was said unrelated power issue?